# How to implement a generic RecyclerView with different types of items (TextView, Button, Spinner)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am developing an Android application in Kotlin to allow a smartphone to communicate with an nRF52840 via BLE to read/write data.

I am developing the view that displays this data. This view comes in the form of different parameters, which can be acted upon (with a button or a spinner) or not (simple TextView containing a data).

So I first created a RecyclerView for each type of view (parameter with TextView, Button or Spinner).

activity.xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_parameters_text"
    tools:listitem="@layout/parameter_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/currentConnexion"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rv_parameters_spinner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_parameters_spinner"
    tools:listitem="@layout/parameter_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_parameters_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rv_parameters_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_parameters_button"
    tools:listitem="@layout/parameter_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_parameters_spinner"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/disconnect"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

parameter_text.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/parameterName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/parameter_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/parameterValue"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/parameterValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/parameter_value"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/parameterName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/parameterName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

parameter_spinner.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/parameterName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/parameter_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/parameterSpinner"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/parameterSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/parameterName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/parameterName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

parameter_button.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/parameterName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/parameter_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/parameterButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/parameterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/parameter_value"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/parameterName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/parameterName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

However, I would like to have only one RecyclerView containing these 3 types of parameters. Can you tell me how I should achieve this?

EDIT:

My RecyclerView is implemented following [this link](https://github.com/afollestad/recyclical)

So I don't have the same implementation as you. So I modified my code this way to make it work:

```
rv_parameters.setup {
    withDataSource(parametersList)
    withItem<ParameterText, ParameterTextViewHolder>(R.layout.parameter_text) {
        onBind(::ParameterTextViewHolder) { _, item ->
            parameterName.text = item.parameterName
            parameterText.text = item.parameterValue
        }
    }
    withItem<ParameterButton, ParameterButtonViewHolder>(R.layout.parameter_button) {
        onBind(::ParameterButtonViewHolder) { _, item ->
            parameterName.text = item.parameterName
            parameterButton.text = item.parameterButton

        }
        onClick {
        }
    }
    withItem<ParameterSpinner, ParameterSpinnerViewHolder>(R.layout.parameter_spinner) {
        onBind(::ParameterSpinnerViewHolder) { _, item ->
            parameterName.text = item.parameterName
            parameterSpinner.adapter = item.parameterAdapter
        }
        onClick {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
// Adapter
private val parametersList = emptyDataSourceTyped<Any>()
```

Everything works except my function to update the value associated with the parameter:

```
private fun updateValue(index: Int, value: String) {
    //parametersList[index].parameterValue = value
    rv_parameters.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own `RecyclerView.Adapter` which will provide different `ViewHolder`s by supporting different view types. The data that backs up your adapter will contain those types (text, spinner, button) and you'll have corresponding `ViewHolder`s for each type.

This a sample implementation I've quickly typed up just so you can get an idea:

```
sealed class MyData {
    data class Data1(val name: String)
    data class Data2(val number: Int)
}

class CustomAdapter(private val dataSet: Array<MyData>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    sealed class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        class ViewHolder1(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textView: TextView
            init {
                textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)
            }
        class ViewHolder2(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textView: TextView
            init {
                textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        if (viewType == 1) {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item1, viewGroup, false)
            return ViewHolder1(view)
        } else {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item2, viewGroup, false)
            return ViewHolder2(view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (viewHolder) {
            is ViewHolder1 -> viewHolder.textView = "${dataSet[position]}"
            is ViewHolder2 -> viewHolder.textView = "${dataSet[position]}"
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(int position) = when (dataSet[position]) {
      is MyData.Data1 -> 1
      is MyData.Data2 -> 2
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to do this, but I edited my updateValue function like this:

```
private fun updateValue(index: Int, value: ParameterText) {
    parametersList.removeAt(index)
    parametersList.insert(index, value)
    rv_parameters.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(index)
}
```